Strategies for handling Maternity leave the last two weeks of the semester
I am about to start my first semester, teaching as a tenure track professor. I’m in the U.S. I also recently found out that I was expecting my third child due mid April. Our spring semester ends at the end of April going into the first week of May.
I am very nervous about telling my department head that I am pregnant, primarily because I am the only woman in the department, there are generational differences, and racial and ethnic differences (he’s an older white man and I’m a younger Black woman). He also doesn’t have children and isn’t the biggest fan of children.
I would like some advice on how to break this to him. Additionally, strategies on handling the last two weeks of the spring semester. I would like to go online and asynchronous. I feel like this would inconvenience my colleagues the least Compared to having them take over for my classes for the last two weeks.
My university does have maternity leave even if you haven’t been there for a full year. I would get six weeks but I might not need this considering I am on a nine month contract.
Thanks in advance!

If your due date is April 15, there is a 17% chance the birth will happen in March.  Plan for that too.  Also plan for a period of disability before the birth.

Six weeks is a very meager amount of maternity leave.  Insist on getting the whole six weeks, no matter what time of year the birth is.

A few thoughts if that's your real name, you might consider changing it. Second, if you are due in April, this is still very early. Seems a little too early to bring it up in the event of a miscarriage. Finally, the end of the semester seems like a good time to be out. Write a good test that a colleague can grade, maybe prerecord a few lectures, instead of having to have a colleague teach half your class.

If you haven't already, you may want to meet with someone in HR, to make sure you are clear on all the details of the leave policy, before talking to your chair.

nine month contract - in two very different ways :-)

Congratulations!  Tell everyone instantly and fully (when you happen to want to do so - no earlier or later than YOU prefer to tell them) ! The law and society is FULLY on your side, nothing is more important than pregnancy. Congratulations!

There shouldn't need to be a strategy. It isn't a game. It is a right you have as a person and it doesn't depend on any lack of chauvinism or racism or sexism or... by your department head.
Tell him of your expected due date. That should be the end of the story. If he can't deal with it, then he can't do his job. At least he has time to plan to cover you and you can help in that. It is much easier than a case in which someone suddenly has a health issue that demands quick action that may not be planned for.
Congratulations. Your life comes first, including your right to have a family and be respected for it.

Break it to him early (and take your full leave entitlement)
There is no particular strategy you need in this situation, save for the fact that it is best to give as much notice as possible.  Agonising over how to break the news to your Department Head in the optimal way is likely to delay this information, and so it is a net negative.  Tell your Department Head about your pregnancy as soon as possible to ensure that the Department has as much time as possible to adapt to your leave.
I suppose it is reasonable to be nervous about how a person might react to your news, but leave is leave --- it is a legal entitlement in your employment contract.  Take all six weeks of your leave and do not make the mistake of feeling pressure to eschew your leave in order to make things easier on your colleagues.  (If anything, put pressure on yourself not to short-change your new baby.)  The fact that you are developing a transition plan is good, and your suggestions sound reasonable to me.  Discuss them with other relevant academics to see the best way to conduct hand-over of your duties and transition into your leave.
Oh, and congratulations!

I cannot imagine a US university that would not have very clear procedures for handling a faculty member having to go on maternity leave in the middle of a semester. Department chairs handle all kinds of strange and difficult business, but this situation should be very straightforward for your chair to handle, in coordination with the relevant administrative/HR units on campus.
I agree with @Buffy that it should not be up to you to devise a strategy for handling the last weeks of the semester. Your department should offer you guidance how to handle this. They may or may not think that asynchronous teaching is an acceptable or ideal solution.
If the chair is bigoted towards you due to your race, sex, or pregnancy status, that is a very serious matter. It’s hard to offer generic advice given that you have not yet suffered any discrimination but are merely fearful of becoming a potential victim of discrimination, but if you have any concerns that you are being mistreated over your pregnancy, I’d suggest consulting an attorney.
In terms of what to do: talk to either the department chair or an HR person on your campus. I don’t think anyone would expect you to initiate this discussion as soon as you learn about the pregnancy, but giving the department at least a few months to plan for your going on leave would probably be considered reasonable and appropriate.
Last but not least: congratulations!

Your profile says you work for a very privileged university.  Not all universities have staff to update their policies.  Not all have functioning HR departments.

@AnonymousPhysicist I said: "I cannot imagine a US university that would not have very clear procedures for handling a faculty member having to go on maternity leave in the middle of a semester." Are you disagreeing with this statement? To be clear, I can imagine a university that wouldn't offer good maternity leave benefits, but even at such a place I'm pretty sure they wouldn't be fazed about how to deal with a faculty member giving birth.

@DanRomik Sadly I think it's far from uncommon for universities to be downright backwards when it comes to accommodating pregnant faculty members appropriately. While it's better than it once was, sexism is still very much entrenched in the system.

To augment the suggestion of consulting an attorney, I'd also suggest getting in touch with the university's faculty association/bargaining unit/whatever it might be called.

@GregMartin I think you missed the point of my earlier clarification. There are two separate issues here: 1. whether the university offers good maternity benefits such as paid leave or other accommodations for faculty members after childbirth. I can see how some universities may not do that. 2. the separate issue of whether the uni will be confused about how to handle a faculty member going on (paid or unpaid) maternity leave. What I said was that I can't imagine a university not knowing how to handle that situation. That's not at odds with being "backwards" in the sense you're referring to.

It's a reasonable clarification, and I agree that the odds are different in the two cases. However, I can definitely still imagine universities or departments not knowing how to handle maternity leave. There are still academic departments who have hired at most one woman in the history of the department....

@GregMartin - the department chair may be clueless, but I'm sure that the university HR policies have dealt with any number of women employees (not just professors).

@JonCuster HR departments tend to have policies for everything, but when left to their own devices, these policies tend to only work well for precisely the type of work done in the HR department. I think at my current institution, if I want to finish preparing my Monday morning lecture over the weekend, I would officially have to apply for a permit to do so and give the precise hours several days in advance. So a policy might be there, but especially if it was never used by a professor, it might be ill-suited for the situation and need severe adjustments involving all sides in order to work.

@AnonymousPhysicist Universities have insurance which isn't eager to pay $80,000 to the lawyers every time somebody goes on medical leave.

You didn't mention your teaching load, but maybe there is some flexibility there?  In exchange for a light or no load in the spring, agree to another coarse in the fall or more coarses next year?
At some schools/departments you aren't expected to teach your first semester, maybe you can move that to your second semester?
A lighter teaching load in the spring won't solve all your problems, but it will help.

Careful about making commitments past the due date. Yes, there are the magic low-maintenance babies, but for most people taking on even more work when they have a baby is not realistic.
